# Node interactive CLI's start slowly

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I've written an interactive CLI using Node and installed the module globally. I noticed that there's a perceptible delay between running the command and getting the interactive prompt. Node's built-in profiling (`--prof`) didn't reveal any bottlenecks. Since noticing this with my own CLI, I've noticed it with other Node interactive CLI's such as yoeman (`yo`). But I don't have this problem with interactive CLI's written in Python. What is the reason for this? Are there tools I could use to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is `node -e ""` slow for you? (For me, it takes half the time of `python3 -c ""`.) If you rule out `node` startup time, then you can start ruling out things in your script. (Start removing things from your code, or start with an empty project and slowly build it back up, and measure at each step until you identify the culprit.)

Comment: To assume that your code is slow for the same reason that `yo` is slow is a bit of a leap. Please edit the question to include your code.

Comment: what is output of executing ...   find  $(echo $NODE_PATH ) | wc
   ...  that env var is where nodejs stores its packages ... maybe you have boat loads of libs ... on a minimal nodejs install prior to adding locally installed packages its about a few thousand files ... under this condition after the inital call to ... node -e  "" is instantaneous

Comment: @smarx my node v. python3 execution times are comparable to yours. However, I'm wondering if this is a difference between node modules that are installed globally vs. executing the file "directly", e.g. `node foo.js`. @ScottStensland the output of `$(echo $NODE_PATH) | wc` is `       0       0       0`. I don't seem to have a node path variable. I'm using n for version management which might account for this?